# How to loop through complex XML nodes in XML file and select values based on a list that has tag meta data attributes?

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking for some sample code  for reading  node value & writing to a | separated file for following xml based on attributes derived out of field definitions tags in same xml file . Field definition tags have been removed for brevity. The code so far cannot take the attributes of user & user group tags to show up the user names, instead of their ID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Rows count="1">
    <Row rowGuid="124d9857-bfdf-4541-8464-10d2e0e588d9" >
        <Row  rowGuid="a68e7a0f-de97-4ab0-a8f2-d60c87fad3fc" >
            <Row rowGuid="5fcd83e3-b59f-4825-8464-f90cccc3a481" >
                <Row  rowGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432">
                    <Field id="6680" >QRS</Field>
                </Row>
                <Field id="82152">KL</Field>
            </Row>
            <Field id="2492" guid="87380cb8-ee70-495e-b06a-627757d55597" type="1">SSS</Field>
            <Field id="9972" guid="66dcea9b-5943-43de-b6d5-8a12c68e17cd" type="1" />
        </Row>
        <Field id="81064" guid="73df6903-9017-43df-bdb0-f72b1a9971ea" type="1">Technical Imaging</Field>
        <Field id="77166" guid="354e7918-74a4-4cb7-810e-339067b81701" type="4">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="440" listValName="No">No</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>
        <Field id="81163" guid="e0049c35-a09a-4e02-9951-c416eef83f7f" type="8">
            <Users>
                <User id="123" firstName="John" lastName="Joseph" domain="QRS">JJ450</User>
            </Users>
            <UserGroups />
        </Field>
        <Field id="81881" guid="4cbd2337-ee2b-48e4-b85f-37666fbd8cd2" type="3" dateConValue="2020-05-19T00:00:00Z">5/19/2020</Field>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

The code I used:

```
public Dictionary<String, string> GetAttributes1()
{
    xDoc.LoadXml(strXml); // Load it straight from the string
    XmlNodeList xnl = xDoc.SelectNodes("/Rows/ColumnDefinitions");
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (XmlNode i in xnl)
    {
        foreach (XmlElement x in i.ChildNodes)
        {
            String nameattr = (String)x.GetAttribute("name");
            String idattr = (String)x.GetAttribute("id");
            dict.Add(idattr, nameattr);
        }
    }
    return dict;

}

Dictionary<string, string> dict_main = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict_main = GetAttributes1();
xDoc.LoadXml(strXml); // Load it straight from the string // 

foreach (XmlNode componentNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("/Rows"))
{
    if (componentNode.Name == "Rows")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in componentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Name == "Row")
            {
                ft = ReadAllNodes(childNode, dict_main);
                //Idea is to get each of the node values through attribute id because for 
                //users node, first & last names need to be concatenated.As of now only 
                //user JJ450 is displayed with other data.Also data needs to be scrubbed
                Console.WriteLine(ft);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desired Output : ( Basically traversing from outer node to inner nodes ..)

> Technical Imaging|No|John Joseph,|5/19/2020|SSS||KL|QRS

Edit:I did not include ReadAllNodes()  because I was stuck in figuring out how to use the attributes here . Attributes I had deleted from XML for brevity.
public string ReadAllNodes(XmlNode node, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{

```
        if (node.ChildNodes.Count >0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            d = dict;
            foreach (XmlNode subNode in node)
            {
                //Recursion
                ReadAllNodes(subNode, d);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
             
            TextConcat = TextConcat + node.InnerText + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return TextConcat;
    }
```

Updated XML format: The output as per columns is in same order as  the Column definitions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Rows count="714">
  <Row contentId="466092" SectionId="44" SectionGuid="086d9857-bfdf-4541-8464-10d2e0e588d9" formId="398" formId="0">
    <Row contentId="223292" SectionId="33" SectionGuid="a68e7a0f-de97-4abe-a8f2-d60c87fad3fc" formId="149" formId="0">
      <Row contentId="605207" SectionId="51" SectionGuid="5fcd83e3-b59f-4825-8464-f90cccc3a481" formId="192" formId="0">
        <Row contentId="223097" SectionId="34" SectionGuid="4a54f032-325e-4988-8621-2cb7b49d8432" formId="191" formId="0">
          <Column id="7880" guid="26524a5e-be65-4710-a01c-7b356f05aee9" type="1">ALLCHEM</Column>
          <Column id="2972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" type="1">Chem</Column>
          <Column id="2973" guid="c90a36e3-b19c-48c5-9f13-cd79b44bd5aa" type="1">"Organic Chemicals, Speciality Division*" </Column>
        </Row>
        <Column id="15152" guid="3c1058f0-2c21-4cb1-965e-b70c61062b59" type="1">SPD</Column>
        <Column id="2987" guid="7bc61414-9782-4566-a310-eee4f11c3835" type="1">Speciality</Column>
        <Column id="2988" guid="8488647e-9050-4410-88bb-13e8b7894696" type="1">"Resin & Allied Chemicals"</Column>
      </Row>
      <Column id="2492" guid="86180cb8-ee70-495e-b06a-627757d55597" type="1"> OL24 White Peak</Column>
      <Column id="3172" guid="78dcea9b-5943-43de-b6d5-8a12c68e17cd" type="1" />
      <Column id="3047" guid="db4553c7-8b67-41f5-9f26-5aec45ec1a4b" type="1">210</Column>
    </Row>
    <Column id="14064" guid="61ae6903-9017-43df-bdb0-f72b1a9971ea" type="1">RatingSystem</Column>
    <Column id="14065" guid="5138109d-23bf-4862-b1b9-0319d41d41f2" type="1">DNBRS</Column>
    <Column id="14060" guid="c693fdbe-53e3-4602-8ee7-a648c2f3baf4" type="6">210-1</Column>
    <Column id="17178" guid="354e7918-74a4-4cb7-810e-339067b81701" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="2740" displayName="No">No</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14063" guid="7858729b-978d-49bc-b791-8447fed372dc" type="1">SPD-210-OL24-100</Column>
    <Column id="14075" guid="29b52040-d342-4db8-a023-048b26b12d69" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63966" displayName="Reporting System">Reporting System</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14163" guid="e0049c35-a79a-4e02-9951-c416eef83f7f" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="4123" firstName="Person1" lastName="Person2" domain="LSG">MRYS</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="16611" guid="a7979101-789e-4f66-831b-433f050e32cc" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="2506" firstName="Person3" lastName="Person4" domain="LSG">TSDE</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14160" guid="e21d612a-64fa-48d7-ad0e-8c89928b7f07" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="2459" firstName="Person5" lastName="Person6" domain="LSG">DR5I</User>
        <User id="2506" firstName="Person7" lastName="Person8" domain="LSG">S23Q</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="15165" guid="a30cd010-7050-4986-9a29-84c311a1cf6b" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="4429" firstName="Person9" lastName="Person10" domain="LSG">BUP2</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="17206" guid="4abd56f6-17d1-45ed-bad4-31889407a50a" type="8" />
    <Column id="14159" guid="ca818c93-78ec-4103-91e9-159d602a5a1f" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="4246" firstName="Person11" lastName="Person12" domain="LSG">VL2N</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14728" guid="34d79ec6-eccd-40a4-b191-9c51275884a5" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="3659" firstName="Person13" lastName="Person14" domain="LSG">SDHW</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14157" guid="7cd2d81f-ec79-4849-a894-f6da62958577" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="3850" firstName="Person15" lastName="Person16" domain="LSG">FSA2</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14161" guid="090aa6f1-ca64-4fa2-b61c-e45842be2872" type="8" />
    <Column id="17802" guid="add09ea3-e280-414a-9516-6eebae12585a" type="8" />
    <Column id="14158" guid="f0853242-b303-4882-a870-9044a7b3be83" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="3205" firstName="Person17" lastName="Person18" domain="LSG">IU9D</User>
        <User id="3768" firstName="Person19" lastName="Person20" domain="LSG">ZW9K</User>
        <User id="4032" firstName="Person21" lastName="Person22" domain="LSG">BAIU</User>
        <User id="4452" firstName="Person23" lastName="Person24" domain="LSG">CVAI</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14164" guid="a25337b1-2e16-49a9-8d93-3a20f2f7727f" type="8">
      <Users />
      <Groups>
        <Group id="184">TMK</Group>
        <Group id="187">LSG-OP</Group>
      </Groups>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14162" guid="71d885e0-3f39-4b02-a8ae-66a39840798e" type="8">
      <Users>
        <User id="3373" firstName="Person25" lastName="Person26" domain="LSG">POQN</User>
      </Users>
      <Groups />
    </Column>
    <Column id="14730" guid="ac434b5d-2fa0-4865-90db-b3e945196798" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="64358" displayName="Process">Processing Plant</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14121" guid="89c5756e-8129-4419-9aea-36ac7da4fa78" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-03-14T00:00:00Z">14/5/2018</Column>
    <Column id="14125" guid="b4867b22-be37-46e0-846a-57a0bd503674" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2022-03-14T00:00:00Z">13/5/2019</Column>
    <Column id="14081" guid="d933419d-dbef-47bb-974a-15237e07a68d" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63969" displayName="Running">Running</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14090" guid="8cf0db5c-6d36-41e5-ad91-1a20cad85721" type="1">Used in the manufacturing of printing inks, adhesives, rubber goods, plastics, paints, coatings and concrete cure</Column>
    <Column id="14629" guid="7f80f67b-7502-48f9-a708-ca4e9fc77d75" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65170" displayName="Derby">Derby</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="15153" guid="d33c92a7-c6f3-4143-8083-51ba766c2c23" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63783" displayName="Low Risk">Low Risk</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="15155" guid="af78d1cd-038f-4e5b-8d6b-51bc849f61fa" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63783" displayName="Hold">Hold</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="15154" guid="1b438351-c077-472d-abb6-e0bd85c6276f" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63783" displayName="Good">Good</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14084" guid="75ab872e-9f27-42d3-9680-bb56cee4350d" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63783" displayName="Moderate">Moderate</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14068" guid="555114ca-e031-4f71-b06e-3e376126a279" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63958" displayName="Yes">Yes</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14910" guid="4830ccb1-2c36-46e1-8059-38367fb7ea36" type="9" />
    <Column id="14717" guid="3a371d7c-6afc-4bfd-88f9-367c8d16d784" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="64356" displayName="UK">Derby</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14748" guid="0dc35337-5687-4121-9bab-36a0af5f425f" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-10-04T00:00:00Z">4/10/2019</Column>
    <Column id="14639" guid="4a557365-eb4a-40c3-9dc3-064f788b5e2c" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="64301" displayName="3">3</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14747" guid="d511631a-6cd0-4310-af93-e3ea09d0e3de" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-10-05T00:00:00Z">5/10/2019</Column>
    <Column id="14884" guid="b5be85c0-9fd2-488c-9469-94ceb3a6da35" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2020-05-19T00:00:00Z">5/19/2020</Column>
    <Column id="14069" guid="fe878d40-4e2c-450d-af20-44e13a2e8210" type="4">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="63961" displayName="N/A">N/A</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Column>
    <Column id="14871" guid="e23db599-ee36-421d-ac0d-b42f0d2c5daf" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-06-09T00:00:00Z">09/6/2019</Column>
    <Column id="15156" guid="f5c9cf48-d548-40d3-896d-6b6e61935d55" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-04-04T00:00:00Z">04/4/2019</Column>
    <Column id="15157" guid="64040235-e543-4ba9-97ce-3f282fdf5628" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2019-04-12T00:00:00Z">12/4/2019</Column>
    <Column id="14881" guid="4cbd2337-ee2b-48e4-b85f-37678fbd8cd2" type="3" xmlConvertedValue="2020-05-19T00:00:00Z">05/19/2020</Column>
  </Row>
    <Metadata>
    <ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition id="14060" guid="c693fdbe-53e3-4602-8ee7-a648c2f3baf4" name="ID" alias="TID" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14063" guid="7858729b-978d-49bc-b791-8447fed372dc" name="GUID" alias="GUID" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14064" guid="61ae6903-9017-43df-bdb0-f72b1a9971ea" name="Name" alias="SolutionName" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14065" guid="5138109d-23bf-4862-b1b9-0319d41d41f2" name="Abbr" alias="Abbr" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14068" guid="555114ca-e031-4f71-b06e-3e376126a279" name="FinancialAudit" alias="FinancialAudit" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14069" guid="fe878d40-4e2c-450d-af20-44e13a2e8210" name="StockPortfolio" alias="Stock" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14075" guid="29b52040-d342-4db8-a023-048b26b12d69" name="SystemType" alias="SystemType" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14081" guid="d933419d-dbef-47bb-974a-15237e07a68d" name="OperationStatus" alias="OperationStatus" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14084" guid="75ab872e-9f27-42d3-9680-bb56cee4350d" name="HighRiskCategory" alias="RiskCategory" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14090" guid="8cf0db5c-6d36-41e5-ad91-1a20cad85721" name="OperationComments" alias="OperationComments" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14157" guid="7cd2d81f-ec79-4849-a894-f6da62958577" name="Trader1" alias="Trader-1" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14158" guid="f0853242-b303-4882-a870-9044a7b3be83" name="Trader2" alias="Trader-2" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14159" guid="ca818c93-78ec-4103-91e9-159d602a5a1f" name="DayTrader1" alias="DayTrader-1" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14160" guid="e21d612a-64fa-48d7-ad0e-8c89928b7f07" name="DayTrader2" alias="DayTrader2" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14161" guid="090aa6f1-ca64-4fa2-b61c-e45842be2872" name="IntraDayTrader1" alias="Information_System_Security_Engineer_ISS" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14162" guid="71d885e0-3f39-4b02-a8ae-66a39840798e" name="SystemAnalyst" alias="SA" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14163" guid="e0049c35-a79a-4e02-9951-c416eef83f7f" name="BA" alias="Business Analyst" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14164" guid="a25337b1-2e16-49a9-8d93-3a20f2f7727f" name="SO" alias="SecurityOfficer" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14629" guid="7f80f67b-7502-48f9-a708-ca4e9fc77d75" name="Location" alias="Location" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14639" guid="4a557365-eb4a-40c3-9dc3-064f788b5e2c" name="Level" alias="Level" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14717" guid="3a371d7c-6afc-4bfd-88f9-367c8d16d784" name="Venue" alias="Venue" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14728" guid="34d79ec6-eccd-40a4-b191-9c51275884a5" name="Chief Risk Analyst" alias="Chief_Risk_Analyst" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14730" guid="ac434b5d-2fa0-4865-90db-b3e945196798" name="Mode" alias="Operation" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14747" guid="d511631a-6cd0-4310-af93-e3ea09d0e3de" name="E-VerifyDate" alias="EVerify_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14748" guid="0dc35337-5687-4121-9bab-36a0af5f425f" name="ReviewDate" alias="Review_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14871" guid="e23db599-ee36-421d-ac0d-b42f0d2c5daf" name="ApprovalDate" alias="Approval_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14881" guid="4cbd2337-ee2b-48e4-b85f-37678fbd8cd2" name="ContingencyDate" alias="Contingency_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14884" guid="b5be85c0-9fd2-488c-9469-94ceb3a6da35" name="ExpirationDate" alias="Expiration_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14910" guid="4830ccb1-2c36-46e1-8059-38367fb7ea36" name="AuditID" alias="Audit_ID" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15153" guid="d33c92a7-c6f3-4143-8083-51ba766c2c23" name="DNBRating1" alias="DNBRating_1" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15154" guid="1b438351-c077-472d-abb6-e0bd85c6276f" name="DNBRating2" alias="DNBRating2" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15155" guid="af78d1cd-038f-4e5b-8d6b-51bc849f61fa" name="DNBRating3" alias="DNBRating3" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15156" guid="f5c9cf48-d548-40d3-896d-6b6e61935d55" name="CreditDate" alias="Credit_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15157" guid="64040235-e543-4ba9-97ce-3f282fdf5628" name="DNBDate" alias="DNB_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15165" guid="a30cd010-7050-4986-9a29-84c311a1cf6b" name="Risk_Advisor" alias="RA" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="16611" guid="a7979101-789e-4f66-831b-433f050e32cc" name="Chief_Risk_Officer" alias="Chief_Risk_Officer" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="17178" guid="354e7918-74a4-4cb7-810e-339067b81701" name="Risk_Mitigated" alias="Risk_Mitigation_Done" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="17206" guid="4abd56f6-17d1-45ed-bad4-31889407a50a" name="CyberAdvisor" alias="Cyber_Advisor" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="17802" guid="add09ea3-e280-414a-9516-6eebae12585a" name="UserList" alias="User_List" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14121" guid="89c5756e-8129-4419-9aea-36ac7da4fa78" name="AuthorizedDate" alias="Authorized_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="14125" guid="b4867b22-be37-46e0-846a-57a0bd503674" name="End_of_Authorization_Date" alias="End_of_Authorization_Date" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="2492" guid="86180cb8-ee70-495e-b06a-627757d55597" name="Office" alias="Office" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="3047" guid="db4553c7-8b67-41f5-9f26-5aec45ec1a4b" name="OfficeDescription" alias="Office_Description" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="3172" guid="78dcea9b-5943-43de-b6d5-8a12c68e17cd" name="Division_Code" alias="Code" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="2987" guid="7bc61414-9782-4566-a310-eee4f11c3835" name="Group_Code" alias="Group_Code" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="2988" guid="8488647e-9050-4410-88bb-13e8b7894696" name="Description" alias="Description" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="15152" guid="3c1058f0-2c21-4cb1-965e-b70c61062b59" name="Unit_Code" alias="Unit_Code" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="2972" guid="e9630a75-1738-49de-bc99-0d93344eee4b" name="Unit_Name" alias="Unit_Name" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="2973" guid="c90a36e3-b19c-48c5-9f13-cd79b44bd5aa" name="Description" alias="Description" />
      <ColumnDefinition id="7880" guid="26524a5e-be65-4710-a01c-7b356f05aee9" name="TickerCode" alias="DNBCode" />
    </ColumnDefinitions>
  </Metadata>
  </Rows>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add a **desired output** based on the input XML.

Comment: Your code isn't valid C# code. Please fix.

Comment: You use xpath `"/Rows/ColumnDefinitions"` - there is no `ColumnDefinitions` element in your xml. Please paste correct xml and correct code.

Comment: `ReadAllNodes` - show us this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below uses xml linq to get all info, just not on one row :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine();  //used to skip first row with utf-16
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            XElement rows = doc.Root;
            List<XElement> xRows = rows.Elements("Row").ToList();

            List<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
            foreach (XElement xRow in xRows)
            {
                List<XElement> xFields = xRow.Descendants("Field").ToList();

                foreach (XElement xField in xFields)
                {
                    Field field = new Field();
                    fields.Add(field);
                    field.fieldId = (int)xField.Attribute("id");
                    if (xField.Attribute("type") != null)
                    {
                        field.type = (int)xField.Attribute("type");
                    }
                    field.value = (string)xField;
                    XElement listValue = xField.Descendants("ListValue").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (listValue != null)
                    {
                        field.listValueId = (int)listValue.Attribute("id");
                        field.listValueName = (string)listValue;
                    }
                    XElement user = xField.Descendants("User").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        field.userId = (int)user.Attribute("id");
                        field.firstName = (string)user.Attribute("firstName");
                        field.lastName = (string)user.Attribute("lastName");
                        field.domain = (string)user.Attribute("domain");
                        field.userText = (string)user;
                    }
                }
            }
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse("<Rows></Rows>");
            XElement xRows1 = doc1.Root;
            Console.WriteLine(Field.header());
            foreach (Field field in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(field.Print());
                xRows1.Add(field.GetElement());
            }
            doc1.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Field
    {
        public int? fieldId { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public int? type { get; set; }
        public int? listValueId { get; set; }
        public string listValueName { get; set; }
        public int? userId { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string userText { get; set; }

        public static string header()
        {
            return string.Join("|", new string[] {
                "Field ID", 
                "Value",
                "Type",
                "List Value Id",
                "List Value Name",
                "User ID",
                "First Name",
                "Last Name",
                "Domain",
                "User Text",
            });
        }
        public string Print()
        {
            return string.Join("|",
                fieldId,
                value,
                type,
                listValueId,
                listValueName,
                userId,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                domain,
                userText
                );
        }
        public XElement GetElement()
        {
            return new XElement("Row", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("fieldId", (fieldId == null) ? string.Empty : fieldId.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("value", (value == null) ? string.Empty : value.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("type", (type == null) ? string.Empty : type.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("listValueId", (listValueId == null) ? string.Empty : listValueId.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("listValueName", (listValueName == null) ? string.Empty : listValueName.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("userId", (userId == null) ? string.Empty : userId.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("firstName", (firstName == null) ? string.Empty : firstName.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("lastName", (lastName == null) ? string.Empty : lastName.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("domain", (domain == null) ? string.Empty : domain.ToString() ),
                new XAttribute("userText", (userText  == null) ? string.Empty : userText.ToString())});

        }
    }
}
```

---

The code below writes the column headers to a csv file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);
            //skip utf16 in first line
            reader.ReadLine();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            List<XElement> ColumnDefinitions = doc.Descendants("ColumnDefinition").ToList();
            string[] columnNames = ColumnDefinitions.Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name")).ToArray();

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about multiple row elements .

Comment: Which row elements?  rows.Elements() gets the top level rows and xRowDescendants("Field") gets multiple Fields.

Comment: Thanks. I gave you a partial XML .Although full XML is well-formed, the format required to put it as | separated file is more complex. Full XML has field definitions which I excluded. I am thinking of using the ID of each filed in the node and create the output file. Can you give me some pointers about doing that ?

Comment: You have a recursive xml file.  Do you need to keep the parent/child relationships?  What is the format that you need for the output?

Comment: I think its better to post the full XML  with 1 row as a sample.Potentially row count will be around 1000.

Comment: The XML just generated root tags .

Comment: o/p text format desired : ID,GUID,Name,Abbr,FinancialAudit,StockPortfolio,SystemType,OperationStatus ,HighRiskCategory,OperationComments,Trader1,Trader2,DayTrader1,DayTrader2 ,IntraDayTrader1,SystemAnalyst,BA,SO,Location,Level,Venue,ChiefRiskAnalyst,Mode ,E-verifyDate,ReviewDate,ApprovalDate,ContingencyDate,ExpirationDate,AuditID ,DNBRating1,DNBRating2,DNBRating3,CreditDate,DNBDate,Risk_Advisor ,Chief_Risk_Officer,Risk_Mitigated,CyberAdvisor,UserList,AuthorizedDate ,End_of_Authorization_Date,Office,OfficeDescription,Division_Code,Group_Code ,Description,Unit_Code,Unit_Name,Description,DNBCode